# parsing a 2 dimension array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file where the data is in this format

```
[ [ 'Apples', '100' ],
  [ 'Oranges', '50' ],
  [ 'Pears', '200' ] ]
```

Can someone please pass me a Python script that shows how to parse this file,Such that I am able to get a handle to the individual array elements. 
i.e 
I can print them Row + Column wise.

I need this in a python script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate a literal array:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
  array = literal_eval(file.read().strip())

for arr in array:
  print(arr)
```

Output:

```
['Apples', '100']
['Oranges', '50']
['Pears', '200']
```

`.strip()` is used to remove leading/trailing spaces/newlines.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np

a = [[ 'Apples', '100' ],
    [ 'Oranges', '50' ],
    [ 'Pears', '200' ] ]

A = np.array(a)

# select a column
col = A[:, 0]

# select a row
row = A[0, :]
```